# $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}${$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ ($\lfloor1^2(\sin x)^x\rfloor$+$\lfloor2^2(\sin x)^x\rfloor$ +......

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor 1^2(\sin x)^x\rfloor+\lfloor 2^2(\sin x)^x\rfloor+\dots+\lfloor n^2(\sin x)^x\rfloor}{n^3}\right)$$

Can anyone help me to solve this one? I think sandwich theorem will be applied. Again getting stuck at $(\sin x)^x$ when $x$ tends $\infty$. $\sin x$ varies between $-1$ to $1$ but making the power $x$ to $\infty$ makes me confusing.

Please Help :)

Comment: How are you defining $(\sin x)^x$ when $\sin x\lt0$?

Comment: @BarryCipra if its exactly -1 then it'll be a different situation and if fraction then its another case too..

Comment: I don't understand your reply.  My point is that, except when $x$ is an integer, $(\sin x)^x$ is not a real number if $\sin x\lt0$, and the floor function makes no sense for those values.

Comment: @Barry Cipra so sorry for that. I got it what you said.. but can u explain a bit further to solve the whole problem..

Answer (score 4):

You want

$\lim_{x \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty} s(n, x)
$
where
$ s(n, x)
=\dfrac1{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor k^2 (\sin(x))^x\rfloor
$.

If
$x = 2m\pi$,
$\sin(x) = 0$,
so
$s(n, x) = 0
$.

If
$x = (2m+1/2)\pi
$,
$\sin(x) = 1$,
so
$s(n, x) = \dfrac1{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2
\to \dfrac13
$.

Therefore
the limit does not exist.

Comment: I was also thinking initially it wont exist because of sine functions wave nature.. answer given 1/3.