# Limit over another limit

Tags: limits

> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor 1^2(\sin x)^x\rfloor+\lfloor 2^2(\sin x)^x\rfloor+\dots+\lfloor n^2(\sin x)^x\rfloor}{n^3}\right)$$

**My attempt**:

I thought that as $x$ was approaching infinity so $0<\lfloor r^2(\sin x)^x\rfloor < r^2$ where $r=1,2,3\dots,n$.  By using sandwich theorem i got the result between $0$ and $1$.  But this does not match the answer.  Please help.

Comment: Please use latex to write equation inside question. https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/amsmath/

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741173/lim-limits-x-to-infty-lim-limits-n-to-infty-lfloor12-sin-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}${$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ ($\lfloor1^2(\sin x)^x\rfloor$+$\lfloor2^2(\sin x)^x\rfloor$ +......](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741173/lim-limits-x-to-infty-lim-limits-n-to-infty-lfloor12-sin-x)

Answer (score 2):

The limit is actually not defined; the limit as $n$ approaches $\infty$ is in fact $\frac{1}{3} (\sin x)^x$, since the sum of squares up to $n$ is a cubic in $n$ with leading coefficient $\frac{1}{3}$. But whenever $x = (2n + \frac{1}{2}) \pi$ for any integer $n$, $\sin x$ is simply 1 and so is $(\sin x)^x$; whenever $x = 2n \pi$, it is simply $0$. So the limit does not exist.

Comment: Extremely sorry sir i forgot to specify that the [.] represents greatest integer function. Can you please tell now

Comment: @Calculuslover it still does not exist; when we use $x = (2n + \frac{1}{2}) \pi$ we obtain $0$, and when we use $x = 2n \pi$ we obtain $\frac{1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + n^2}{n^3}$ which still approaches $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: but the answer given is 1/3

Comment: Can you help please